# unable link pyhton3 in gvim 8.2

Tags: python-3.x, vim, youcompleteme

i'm unable to install YouAutoComplete on vim because he cannot link to python. i've installed python3.8 and 3.7 32bits but it don't change anything(i'm running on windows). And i changed pythonthreedll and pythonthreehome variable without any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in past. I download python-3.8.6-amd 64bit and gvim_8.2 64 bit. Maybe you test it with thiis one's. I had download the gvim from this page: https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases
GVim must have python 3 support. You can test this in Vim with :py3 pass

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i switched to linux and it worked just fine