# Windows: Vim compiled with Python (3.6.0+) support

Tags: python, windows, vim, youcompleteme

How can I resolve the error. I have this error on windows when I try to download two plugins on vim.

Error: `YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (3.6.0+) support.`

- Plug 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': './install.py --tern-completer' }
- Plug 'codota/tabnine-vim'

I have installed the last version of Python but I don't know what happen whit this.

I'm so sorry if a write something wrong, English is not my first language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64954779/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Byoucompleteme%5D+windows+python, http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#python-dynamic